# Histogram with Seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'd like to plot an Histogram which makes comparisons between two arrays of data. Basically, i want to make exactly this:

[image: The plot. i want to make]

Suppose i want to make this plot, but using two arrays with four entries, one with the numbers which should go to the blue areas, and the other with the ones for the blue areas. I have tried this:

```
x1 = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3])
x2 = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.5])
sns.histplot(data=[x1,x2], x=['1','2','3'], multiple="dodge", hue=['a','b'], shrink=.8)
```

But it gives me the error *“ValueError: arrays must all be same length”*

I know that i'm supposed to enter a df and not arrays, but sadly i'm not really an expert on how to use them.
How can i solve this problem? Simply put, i'm looking for a copy and paste solution here, in which i can then change the numbers, and the name of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want a barplot, not a histogram.  Creating a seaborn plot from multiple columns usually involves converting them to ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data), making the process less straightforward.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
x2 = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.5])
x = ['1', '2', '3'] # or, simpler, x = np.arange(len(x1)) + 1
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': x1, 'b': x2, 'x': x})
df_long = df.melt('x')
ax = sns.barplot(data=df_long, x='x', y='value', dodge=True, hue='variable')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot from arrays]

The long form looks like:

```
   x variable  value
0  1        a    0.1
1  2        a    0.2
2  3        a    0.3
3  1        b    0.1
4  2        b    0.2
5  3        b    0.5
```

See [pandas' `melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for additional options, such as naming the  created columns.

Comment: You could experiment with [seaborn's styles and themes](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html). For example `sns.set_style('white')` at the start, and `sns.despine()` at the end.

Comment: Would you know how to add error bars to the above graph? So, let's assume i also know the variance of the data, how can i generate something like the following: 
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Comment: Seaborn calculates these error bars if you provide a lot of values for each x-position. Default a 95% confidence interval for the mean is drawn. With `ci='sd'` it would calculate the standard deviation (but also would need all the data).

Comment: For example, if i needed a barplot with only one colour, but error bars, using the x_1, x_2 i gave you above, how should i do it? Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by "only one color"?  Just `sns.barplot(data=df_long, x='x', y='value', ci='sd')`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only the blue bars (instead of blue/orange), but with standard deviation

Comment: So, does `sns.barplot(data=df_long, x='x', y='value', ci='sd')` work for you? With the current data there is only an error bar for the third value, as the two first have a standard deviation of 0. If there is only one bar per value, you can also use `sns.barplot(data=df_long, x='x', y='value', ci=None, yerr=[sd1, sd2, sd3])` to draw precalculated error bars.